# GeoServer with OpenLayers map showing problem

Tags: geoserver, c#, asp.net, geoserver-rest-api

I have a `GeoServer` service running on `8888` port and the URL is `http://localhost:8888/geoserver`. I can browse any layer created by my custom data, like:

```
http://localhost:8888/geoserver/jantrik/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=jantrik:BGD_roads&styles=&bbox=88.10850235226,20.75222215270564,92.63503571179656,26.62027475965039&width=394&height=512&srs=EPSG:2244&format=application/openlayers&
```

If I visit above link it shows me an image with their control like this:

[image: Bangladesh roads]

Now I want to access it grammatically. For that reason I created a asp.net web application and wrote code to access map:

```
 public string GetMap(string name)
        {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8888/geoserver/wms/reflect?layers=" + name);

            using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
            {
                FileStream imageStream;
                using (imageStream = new FileStream(@"E:\image.png", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
                    if (responseStream != null) responseStream.CopyTo(imageStream);
                }
            }
            return @"E:\image.png";
        }
```

**`But how can I get the values of Layers, Workspaces and other information.`**

Comment: I'm not clear about exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you should try accesing `http://localhost:8888/geoserver/wms/?request=getcapabilities`

Comment: Yep,It gives me all information. It will work.But if i have specific information by workspace or layer name, then it will be better.

Comment: if your workspace is called `foo` the use: `http://localhost:8888/geoserver/foo/wms/?request=getcapabilities`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on want to do with layers and workspaces, and whether or not that functionality exists through the provided api.

For example, [Boundless describes](http://boundlessgeo.com/2012/10/adding-layers-to-geoserver-using-the-rest-api/) an approach to add a new workspace using curl and an api to workspaces

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type:text/xml' -d '<workspace><name>earthws</name></workspace>' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces
```

The same api provides access to create, list, alter, define, delete workspaces, namespaces, datastores, layers, layergroups, styles, etc. - using GET, PUT, DELETE or POST'ing XML to the relevant REST endpoint

api documentation:
http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.0/user/extensions/rest/rest-config-api.html

api examples (using curl):
http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.0/user/extensions/rest/rest-config-examples.html